# Chunked data writes with the Datastax Java driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

When using Astyanax as the client library for Cassandra there's a [Chunked Object Store feature](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Chunked-Object-Store) for storing large files. I can't find any documentation or examples related to the Datastax driver that shows that I can store large files like Astyanax do (chunked and with multiple threads).

Can this be done with the Datastax Driver as well and in such case, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. In the end I've implemented my own Chunked Persister on top of the Datastax driver that runs its own 10 threads Executor and split/merge objects on save and get.